# QT - Unknown debugger type "No engine"

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Recently I have re-installed **QT (5.5.1 MSVC 2013, 32 bit, rev. b52c2f91f5)** on my PC and installed the [debugging tools of Microsoft.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891)

QT (QT Creator) can auto-detect these just fine.

[image: Auto-detect]

When trying to start the debugger with either the default shortcut <kbd>F5</kbd> or clicking it manually, it throws an error that the debugger could not be run. (Compiling works fine, debugging not at all)

[image: Debugger could not be started]

No debugger-engine of type "No engine" could be created.

*(Running Windows 8.1 with VS2013/VS2015 installed - QT working with VS2013 32&64 bit).*

On my work PC I did the same process a few weeks ago and had no problems at all.

**What could cause this problem ? Yet I have only found questions with the same problem related to other compilers.**

Comment: Note: When re-installing QT - or upgrading to a newer QT version, the previously detected debuggers might be set automatically by QT. Pay attention to always check in `Options -> Build & Run -> Kits -> Your installed version` that the correct debugger for the installed version of QT is set. QT set my debugger after an upgrade to x86 whilst I installed x64.

Comment: This might help you because it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361400/unable-to-create-a-debugging-engine-in-qt-editor

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may point to a missing component in your installation process or an actual defect in Qt:

**Option #1**

Install a debugger.

> If you are installing 5.5.1 for Visual Studio 2013 64 or 32bit, 2012
>   32bit, 201032bit.  Then install [windows Debuggers](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html).
>
> Qt will detect automatically the compiler and Debugger.
>
> To set manually `Tools->options->build&run->kits->set one of auto detected` , then
>   you can see all.

Source: https://forum.qt.io/topic/59974/unknown-debugger-type-no-engine/11

**Option #2**

> Unable to create a debugger engine of the type "No engine"

in the past pointed to a bug in the Qt Creator, if you'll update it may be fixed.

I'm also aware that alternatively, it may be solved by updating to Python 2.7.1.

Comment: Good sh#t. I forgot to set the debugger in the kits to the MSVC version. Thanks for that catch. - Tried python, but that is a bug related to another compiler, not MSVC.

Comment: Qt's link leads to a Microsoft page where you can install Windows Debuggers for Windows 10. If you're looking to install Windows Debugging Tools for Windows 7, install the SDK (you can choose to install only the Winows Debugging Tools.) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138

Comment: After installing the windows debugger, I had to manually change to one of the automatically detected debuggers. Just an FYI, as it did not automatically select it.

Comment: Thank you @kayleeFrye_onDeck for your feedback

Comment: Great answer. Here is updated link with Microsoft cdb.exe https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg (Get Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg) (from the SDK))

Answer (score 8):

1. Close Qt Creator.
2. In the folder where your .pro file resides, there will be some .pro.user and .pro.user.x files. Delete them all. Keep only your .pro file.
3. Start Qt Creator and open your .pro file. Qt Creator will ask you to reconfigure your project. Accept that.
4. Now you can debug again, or at least I could; the problem happened to me when I had just updated Qt Creator.

Comment: Simple and util to me. In "options.." I had two instances of the same debuggers registered as "auto". The first was marked with error and I couldn't delete it. Your solution leaves just one debugger in "auto" and works. (I have MinGW version of Qt Creator running on Windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem in windows 7 but I've solved it:

1. Download Windows driver kit 
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800
2. Add your debugger
   [image: -]
3. Change auto-detected kit debugger to your added debugger

Comment: I'm not sure what the driver kit has to do with the debuggers. Doesn't seem like an answer to the question to me. Installing the debugging tools of Microsoft & getting the QT-settings right is "all" you have to do.

Comment: @Blacktempel According the Microsoft website, there are two ways to get the Windows debugger: either install the Windows SDK or install the DDK. If your problem is that you don't have a debugger installed at all (that was the problem for me) then this is a valid answer, although I actually went for the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I **installed Debugging Tools for Windows** and the debugger appeared under `Manage Kits > Build & Run > Debuggers` but it **didn't added in the kits** so I had to go to `Manage Kits > Build & Run > Kits` then **select** the desired **kit** and under `Debugger` I had to select the debugger. Initially the debugger is set to "None".

Answer (score -2):

Answering the title of this question, not the person asking it.

I had the exact same error message on arch linux 64 trying to compile for arm android.

First I ran the gdb debugger in the command line to get the root issue:

```
~/tools/android/android-ndk-r12/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/gdb-orig:
error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libncurses is the issue!  (As of 6/24/2016) Arch linux is on ncurses 6.0-4.  Later you'll also find libtinfo.so.5 is missing.

At this point, the method for fixing the problem is up to you; I don't like using a bunch of AUR repos, so I executed a simple hack.  We're forcing the library linkage that was in libncurses 5x to point at 6x.

## Please ensure you don't overwrite anything before running these commands

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libncursesw.so.6.0 libncurses.so.5
sudo ln -s libncursesw.so.6.0 libtinfo.so.5
```

Re-run your arm gdb, and it should work.

Comment: Don't blindly do these symlinks. If library version has been bumped it's because it's not ABI compatible. Instead check if your distribution has old compatibility version for ncurses. For example in fedora you can simply install `ncurses-compat-libs`.

Comment: People still use fedora?!