# Unable to create a debugging engine in QT editor

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I have recently installed Qt Creator 4.8.0 based on Qt 5.12.0 and I have it configured like in the image below. However, I haven't managed to start the debugger. As it can be seen, the debugger is correctly set for this kit, the one I'm using right now.

[image: Configuration of QT plugins]

Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to debug across a remote platform or on the same host where QtCreator is running?

Comment: It is in the same host

Comment: what is your host running, OS and version?

Comment: Intel I7, 32GB ram. Windows 10 Home 64 bits build: 17134.523

Comment: I've never had any issues with debugging, just ensure your project is built for debug not release then click on the debug icon.

Comment: Effectively, the built is configured  as debug. However, it still continues saying the same. What Kit do you use and how it is configured?. Thanks

Comment: I'll take a look at my build settings when I get infront of my system, won't be for several hours...

Comment: it is not needed anymore. I answered myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow! I found it!!! Here in the tab "projects", there are several build and run configurations. Despite you select a default kit, the final one being executed is the one in black under this tab.

[image: Before solving]

Finally I disabled all of them except the one that was properly configured in the Kits window and it worked. I hope this information is helpful for someone. I don't think that part of the configuration is clear.

[image: After solving]

Comment: It even solved my problem with `std::thread` :) Now I can hate the MSVC a little bit more

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error, but in my case I was using the MSVC compiler and the kit didn't manage to find the CDB debugger. I was able to fix it by going to "Add or remove programs" -> "Windows Software Development Kit" -> Modify -> Change -> Debugging Tools for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was needed to select "Enable C++" under Debugger settings
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYyp2.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to completely trash all of Qt Creator's settings in `C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject` in order to get debugging working again.

Answer (score 0):

The same dumm error QT creator shows when you simply don't have gdb installed.
Worked in my case ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in MacOS, debugger suddenly stopped working (LLDB debugger worked in XCode but not Qt Creator).

In this case, I reinstalled Qt Creator and reinitialized the config by removing the *.config/QtProject* directory located in homedir. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when Qt Creator didn't recognized the path to the Debugger. Due to some reason it showed multiple Auto-detected Debuggers at the same location. And on the top one of the list with the red error indicator.

see

Projects->Manage Kits...->Debuggers

I removed the erroneous Debugger and restart the Qt Creator.

Comment: The MSYS2/Mingw-w64 setup seems to install "hooks" for all the possible toolchains they supply - even if you **haven't** installed them all...

Answer (score 0):

Same error here, in my case GDB was not installed in my docker container where the qt-creator is executed.